# How can I specify Bindings for Command and CommandParameter within a Style?

Tags: .net, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, commandparameter

I have a number of Buttons like this

```
<Button Content="A" 
        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" 
        CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, 
                                   Path=Content}" />
```

where the `Content` property of the Button is being passed as the `CommandParameter`. A single Command in the ViewModel handles all the Buttons and 'knows what to do' based on that parameter (think of a control panel / keyboard type app).

This makes for a lot of repeated XAML. How can I put this repeated code into the base style for a Button?

Comment: I am the victim of a revenge down-vote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is not supported for Silverlight within WP7, in the same way that it was not supported in the browser-based Silverlight before SL4 (see [the following workaround](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx)). You could do one of the following:

1. Create a user control that encapsulates a Button with the bindings you have shown in your question.
2. Sub-class Button, and create your bindings in the C# code of your subclass.

Personally, I would go for (2). This means you can still style your Buttons in the usual way.